# Angular single page application with angular-oauth2-oidc unable to get identity claims. How can I evaluate the token after the initCodeFlow method?

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, angular-oauth2-oidc

I created a SPA angular application and trying to authenticate the api of a third party to be able to make requests. I encounter the problem, that the getIdentityClaims() method always return null.

```
get token(){
    this.claims = this.oauthService.getIdentityClaims();

    var accessToken = this.oauthService.getAccessToken();
    var idToken = this.oauthService.getIdToken();
    
    if(this.claims){
      console.log('-- home claims--', this.claims);
    }
    return this.claims ? this.claims : null;
  }
```

claims, accessToken and idToken are always null after a successful login.

How can I retrieve the IdToken?

And it is not a CORS problem I checked but I am not sure if I use the oauth-oidc library correctly.

I use the `angular-oauth2-oidc@10.0.3` ng module with angular 11.

After the successful login the application is redirected to the home component where the token should be evaluated.

This is what I get after a the login is completed:

[image]

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OAuthModule } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    NavComponent,
    ContactComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    OAuthModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { authCodeFlowConfig } from '../config/sso.config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  claims;
  
  constructor(
    private oauthService:OAuthService,
    private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.configSso();
  }

  async configSso(){
    this.oauthService.configure(authCodeFlowConfig);
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin();
  }


  async login(){
    console.log('login');
    this.oauthService.setupAutomaticSilentRefresh();
    this.oauthService.initCodeFlow();
  }
  async logout(){
    console.log('logout');
    this.oauthService.logOut();
  }

  get token(){
    this.claims = this.oauthService.getIdentityClaims();
    if(this.claims){
      console.log('-- Login claims--', this.claims);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
    }
    return this.claims ? this.claims : null;
  }
}
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  claims;
  constructor(private oauthService:OAuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  get token(){
    this.claims = this.oauthService.getIdentityClaims();

    var accessToken = this.oauthService.getAccessToken();
    var idToken = this.oauthService.getIdToken();
    
    if(this.claims){
      console.log('-- home claims--', this.claims);
    }
    return this.claims ? this.claims : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but perhaps helpful: you could clone [my sample repository](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/) and update the configuration to match your Identity Server. If you just run it straight up, you should be able to log in and see identity claims in the browser page. (Which works against the default sample IDS.) - Perhaps this will help you track the issue in your own situation?

Comment: @Jeroen thanks for your help I will compare my solution with your sample repo